# WordPress管理画面のページング部分のリンクURLでドメイン名が抜けた状態になってしまう

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPressの管理画面において、カスタム投稿の投稿が複数ある場合に右上あたりに出るページングボタンについてです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このボタンをクリックするとブラウザのエラーページになります。（This site can’t be reached）
その際のブラウザのURL部分は `https://wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=news&paged=2` となっており、ドメイン部分が抜けています。

ページング部分のhtmlを解析ツールで見ても、やはりaタグのhrefの中身がドメインが抜けている状態のようでした。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

2ページ目以降のページ自体は存在しており、ドメインが入ったurlを直打ちしたらアクセスすることはできます。

PHP 7.2.8
WordPress 5.3.2

（phpとワードプレスのバージョンを上げることがちょっと難しい状態です。）